# How to set custom image icon in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android

As the title says, i am trying to add a custom image.png to my bottom Navigation bar but i can't find exactly how.

I tried:

Vector asset and image asset does not show my image.png

create a selector xml for my image and added it to my nav menu but it just shows a grey square instead of image

I think the solution must be simple but can't find anything related on this forum.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

bottom_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/airplane"
        android:icon="@drawable/vegetables"
        android:title="Vegetable"
        />


</menu>
```

vegetables.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/veg" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/veg1" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide some of your work tried so far

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman i have really just done a simple bottom navigation menu but i just dont know how to set my custom image.png as icon

Comment: Please add your image.png file

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman https://imgur.com/a/Y8xP9O4

Answer (score 7):

I recommend use a vector image.

Android by default in bottom navigation view component all SVG object displays in white color. The check symbol object is in the circle but his color is converted to white and so it has became invisible.

One solution is to redraw the SVG image. But sometimes it is not posible. The other solution is to tell the bottom navigation view to display original picture colors. You can do it in the activity code setting:

At create() just set:

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: Worked like charm!!. Thanks @Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Update your icon in **`navigation.xml`** like below:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_more"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/title_more" />
```

Here example of **`ic_navigation_more.xml`**:

```
<vector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: And what is pathdata? I need a path for my image.png

Comment: Your image.png is not optimized for menu icon. Either you can use a vector drawable with 24dp or create  PNG using help of android studio

Comment: I tried converting my png to svg online and then i opened 'create new vector assest' in android studio and located the svg converted but it showed an error that there is no vector in my selected svg

Comment: That's not the right way, check tutorial online regarding that

Answer (score 0):

1. Create menu file for your bottom navigation
2. Set icon for every menu item that you have by `android:icon="@drawable/your_drawable"`
3. In xml file where you declared BottomNavigationView add `app:menu="@menu/your_menu"`

Comment: Already done that, but the icon i set for my menu item is a custom image.png and if i set it using android:icon="@drawable/image.png" it shows a grey scare

Comment: Try to set `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"` if it works right then the problem is in using png, you should probably use svg there.

Comment: It does work on default icons, but i need a custom image which i want to set as icon

Comment: Try online converter from png to svg, also scale it down because your png could be too big.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how am i supposed to use the svg? Tried rescaling it as i thought the png was too big i resized it to 24 pixelsx24 pixels. But it still shows a grey square

Comment: I tried converting my png to svg online and then i opened 'create new vector assest' in android studio and located the svg converted but it showed an error that there is no vector in my selected svg. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Custom image with the navigation menu item id

For kotlin:

```
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val BVMenu = navView.getMenu()  
BVMenu.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
```

For Java:

```
Menu navView = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
navView.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
```

Comment: Can't i set it in xml? When i try to set the icon to my custom image it just shows a grey square

Comment: Here I have given you a way to set image programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your `image.png` must have a transparent area, NavigationView will color it just `like the notification icon` on statusbar

Comment: It already has a transparent background i can edit my post and upload my image if needed

Comment: I try to draw something with transparent background, and it work normally, so I think maybe you can upload your image (`I download the image you uploaded on imgur, and that was not a truely transparent`) if you don't mind this.

Answer (score 0):

android:icon="@drawable/your_drawable"

and to solve colour problem tint

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can add a .png image as a navigation view unless you set the icon tint list "setItemIconTintList" to null.
in my case
//navView.setItemIconTintList(null)

Answer (score -1):

In your xml file add the menu property to the BottomNavigationView tag:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_items" /> `
```

The @menu/menu_navigation_items is a menu with < item>  tags. In each item tag add the icon property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:title="Your Title"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/id2"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:title="Your Title"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Yes already done that but android:icon="@drawable/image" in which image.png is my case does not display my image as icon correctly i just see a grey square, i need to set my custom image.png as icon on this navigation.

Comment: Could you provide code snippets for BottomNavigationView and for it's menu?

Comment: sorry i was late had to copy it to phone to post it. Edited my post above with the code needed